# What is the tense and part of speech of "come up"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the tense and part of speech of "come up"?

> Once you **have come up** with potential solutions, the goal then is to make a plan as what ones will be put into action

Comment: "Come" is a past participle, and hence untensed.  "Come up" is two words, thus belongs to two parts of speech. "come" is a verb, and "up" is a preposition. It is not a compound verb (phrasal verb)despite what some grammar books may tell you.

Comment: @BillJ, while I agree that **come up** might not be a phrasal verb as the meaning is exactly the same as come and up on their own, **come up with** is definitely a phrasal verb, as the meaning and usage is completely different. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-up-with-something

Comment: @JavaLatte "Come up with potential solutions" consists of a verb + a preposition with no complement + a preposition with an NP complement. The term "phrasal verb" is misleading. It's not the whole expression "come up with" that is a verb, but just the lexeme "come". Traditional grammar is wrong about all this.

Comment: You really think that "come up with" *isn't* a phrasal verb? The *come* seems to me to mean something very different than it does in its purely literal sense; I am not arriving anywhere when I come up with an idea.

Comment: @stangdon Which is why it is best called a "verbal idiom", i.e. a combination of words whose meaning is not predictable from the meanings of the components. "Come up with" is not a constituent at word level: it’s a VP. Verb is a word category, like noun,
adjective, etc., and it’s "come" that is a verb: this is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we have "He came up with an idea", but not *"He come upped with an idea"